# Redshift COPY - get rejected rows in a file

Tags: amazon-redshift

Here's the situation:

Some 3rd party is dumping csv data into an S3 bucket. This data we want to load to Redshift. Since we have no control over the quality of the data sent to us, we have to consider the possibility of some errors occurring during the COPY to Redshift. We don't want to simply ignore them, so we are looking for ways to understand those load errors.

The idea so far is:
Set MAXERROR to the maximum allowed number, load what can be loaded, and have a look at the rejected rows afterwards. The latter can be done by querying the STL_LOAD_ERRORS and STL_LOADERROR_DETAIL tables of Redshift.

The problem here is that these tables, although the attributes STL_LOAD_ERRORS.raw_line, STL_LOAD_ERRORS.raw_field_value and  STL_LOADERROR_DETAIL.value do exist, they are limited in size to a length of 1024, while one of the columns we get is a huge JSON string that can easily reach 20k+ in length. Also, these error tables, as far as I understand, only hold the information on the columns that actually caused the problem, not other columns (like e.g. the primary key columns that could help in identifying the bad rows).

So my question is:
Is there a way of telling COPY to dump the rejected rows completely into some sort of rejected_file for later analysis?

Comment: You shouldn't be forced to do this by the 3rd party's low data quality, but you might want to consider writing your own parser which checks each line of the data.  It wouldn't be too difficult to do that, and you could keep it as a tool to use later on as well.